# Moving a game from game library to inventory on Steam

Tags: steam

I was wondering if I could move a game from my library to my inventory.

Because my friend bought a game called "Lords of the Fallen", it does not work on his 
PC, so I was thinking if I could trade with him one of my own games *that is in my inventory* called "Torchlight 2" with his game in his library.

Is this possible ?
Is there any time limits for this transaction?

Any help would be appreciated and thank you.

Comment: To add to the answer that you already have, your friend's situation will change sooner or later. When it does they can try the game again.

Answer (score 14):

No, this is not possible.

You cannot change items in your library into inventory items.

Comment: I can vouch for this.  You can go from inventory to library, but *not* library to inventory.

Answer (score 11):

This is not possible. Once a game is in your library, it is permanently added to your library and cannot be gifted, traded or otherwise transferred to someone else.

If your friend bought a game without checking the system requirements, they might be able to get a refund by asking Steam Support. Technically, Valve's policy is not to give refunds in this case  but from personal experience they do (they at least give store credit) if the request is polite and the game genuinely hasn't been played.

Note that if your friend bought the game in the same transaction as other games, Steam may refund the entire transaction, including games in it that worked.

Comment: Do note that, in my experience, they will refund the entire transaction.  Meaning that if you purchased anything else at the same time, that will also be refunded.  Which is bad during sales.

Comment: @Powerlord Adding that to my answer.

Comment: @Studoku That last sentence you edited in is a bit confusing, and doesn't become clear until you read the related comment. You may want to clarify a that bit.